# How can I return a value (true or false) to see if an element is being hovered without hovering on it in REACT

Tags: reactjs, hover, state

I have a navigation bar, when clicking on the navigation bar it setState and opens a sub navigation bar. I would like to set an animation with the submenu if there is no activity(not hovered) after 20 seconds on the submenu.

1. idea - Hover(), mouseover/out, mouseenter/leave is not a solution, because what if after opening the submenu there is no activity at all (mouse doesn`t enter, doesn`t leave the submenu element etc.). - so it is not a solution
2. idea - when setting the state to open the submenu with setTimeOut() set the state again to 20 seconds so the animation starts automatically and create a function on mouseover to set the state back - not a solution at all

---

solution: using setTimeout and then cleartimeout on mouse enter

Comment: Why do you think setTimeout() is not a solution?

Comment: Because let`s say after activating the subnavbar from the navbar the setTimeout sets the state to 'navbarHidden' after 20s. If I write a function for mouse enter to set the state to 'navbarShow' and mouseleave to 'navbarhidden' the settimeout will still be activated to hide it when clicking on the main navbar at the first place.

Comment: I think you’re breaking your own rules with point 1. You say: no activity (not hovered) in your question - logically, this condition is satisfied, if the mouse does not move. What do you want to happen? The user needs to be constantly moving the mouse for 20 seconds and then they get the sub nav bar?

Comment: You can call clearTimeout(yourTimeout) when needed if something happens before these 20s.

Comment: I get what you mean. I just need to figure out how to call clearTimeout from my child component onmouseenter.

Comment: Xizario - Your comments helped me to find the solution. Thanks a lot.